# Query by date does not return results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to make a query for the expiration_date field where it returns the ones that your date is today, I'm trying with that, but it doesn't return any results

```
router.get('/date/expired/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const start = new Date()
    start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

    const end = new Date()
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)
    try {
      const data = await Tarea.find({
        fecha_vencimiento: {
          $gte: start,
          $lt: end
        }
      })

      res.status(200).json({
        data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your dates using `moment.js`:

```js
let start = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
let end = moment().add(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I hope it'll work for you.